# Unexpected NullPointerException from removeAttribute() on JSP redeploy

Tags: java, jsp, nullpointerexception, tomcat7, scriptlet

Being in a rush for a release, I had to integrate a portion of a JSP made with custom tags with another part, that shows some informations with scriptlest.

To make the two work together, I exposed an object from the tag handler `doStartTag()` to the request scope, retrieved that object in the scriptlet, and then removed it at the end of the tag handler execution flow, inside `doEndTag()`.

Some code should clarify my situation.

Here's the relevant part of the tag handler:

```java
public int doStartTag() throws JspException {
    // ...

    // obj is a private member
    pageContext.setAttribute("productFromTag", obj, PageContext.REQUEST_SCOPE);

    return EVAL_BODY_INCLUDE;
}

// ...

public int doEndTag() throws JspException {
    pageContext.removeAttribute("productFromTag", PageContext.REQUEST_SCOPE);
    return EVAL_PAGE;
}
```

And this is the portion of the JSP where the object is retrieved and processed:

```html
<pre:product><!-- this adds the Product instance to the request scope -->
<div class="item">

    <!-- other HTML -->

         <p class="productName"><prod:name></prod:name></p>
         <%
            Product p = (Product) request.getAttribute("productFromTag");
            // Use p

         %>

         <!-- other HTML -->
   </div>
</pre:product>
```

Everything works fine after the first deploy, but if I replace the JSP (say after an edit), the `removeAttribute()` method throws a `NullPointerException`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doRemoveAttribute(PageContextImpl.java:398)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.removeAttribute(PageContextImpl.java:387)
    at xx.xxxxx.xxxx.ProductTag.release(ProductTag.java:89)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TagHandlerPool.release(TagHandlerPool.java:165)
    at org.apache.jsp.modelli.camediResponsive.catalogo.schedaProdotto_jsp._jspDestroy(schedaProdotto_jsp.java:200)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.destroy(HttpJspBase.java:60)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.destroy(JspServletWrapper.java:478)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:166)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    ... 83 more
```

By reading [`removeAttribute()` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspContext.html#removeAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), no exception should be thrown.
Am I misreading the docs? Am I doing something wrong?
I usually replace (i.e. *redeploy*) JSP's, both when editing inside Eclipse or in running production applications, but I've neved faced this situation.

Of course I've already added a `catch()` around the method invocation, but I'm puzzled about why this is happening.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Seth Did you see the *"Of course I've already added a catch() around the method invocation, but I'm puzzled about why this is happening"* part of my question?

Comment: Do you understand the purpose of canonical Q&As?

Comment: @Seth This is not a question about how to fix an NPE, this is a question about why an NPE is thrown from *that* method, when, to my understanting, it should not be thrown.

Comment: Okay. Just in case I'm missing out on something, what exactly do you mean with "replacing the JSP"?

Comment: @Seth When you edit a JSP inside Eclipse, it automatically *replaces* that resource to the local Tomcat instance; or in a deployed webapp running on a standalone Tomcat instance, if you copy-paste a JSP over another, the JSP deployed within the webapp is *replaced*, effectively showing the new code without the need to stop and start the whole webapp.

Comment: Okay, that's something that you should add to your question since as of now it's quite unclear (which is why I flagged it initially). Does the NPE occur regardless of what you change?

Comment: does `if(pageContext.getRequest() != null)` around the removeAttribute fix it?